# Filename becomes gibberish

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

Using JDownloader to download some files makes the filename looks like ".æ­·å²è¬åï¼çç æ¸¯ä¸é" on my file system. The original filename is in Chinese. Is this a encoding issue? (original encoding not UTF-8). If that's the case, can this be recovered? I am guessing to find a encoding converter, and convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You' re looking for [`convmv`](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/), tye `man convmv` for more information.

> converts filenames from one encoding to another

Answer (score 1):

Before recovery filename with convmv, I found this encoding detection tool - [Universal online Cyrillic decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en), which helps me to figure out the "current encoding".